# How do I grab the first 10% of lines in a text file?

Tags: bash

I have a test file with multiple columns. I want to sort based on column 8 which contains numerical values, and then grab the first 10% lines and export them to a new file.

I'd prefer to do this in bash. I know I can do sort -k8 -n for the sorting, but i've been unable to accomplish the second task.

For output:

If my text file has 1000 lines, I only want the first 100.

Files are tab delimited.

Thank you!

Comment: what have you tried looking for with google? seems like you need to use the search terms "bash get first lines of file", "bash count lines in a file", "bash divide integers"

Comment: if you know your number of lines you need (currently 100 lines) then why not to use simply: `head -n 100` ?

Comment: I've already tried looking at various google searches. There are tons of methods for grabbing the first N lines, but I want the first N % of lines.

@KristoMägi This was an example, my pipeline runs hundreds of samples and calls 'binding sites' for each sample, and the numbers are always vastly different which is why i'm trying to get the first 10%.

Comment: If you don't know the total number of lines ahead of time, you need to read through the whole file to determine it before you can compute 10% of it. `sort` doesn't provide that information.

Comment: Yes, i'm aware that I need to determine how many lines there are ahead of time ... that's fairly simple using `wc -l`, what I don't know how to do is pipe all these commands together to get the output i'm looking for. I haven't been successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can fit the whole file in memory, then you can send the output to awk:

```
sort -nk8 file | awk '{ a[NR] = $0 } END { 
  for (i = 1; i <= NR / 10; ++i) print a[i] 
}'
```

Each line is saved in the array `a`, indexed by the line number. The first `NR / 10` lines are printed.

If you have GNU awk you could even do the sorting at the same time:

```
awk '{ a[NR] = $0 } END { 
  asort(a, b, "@val_num_asc"); for (i = 1; i <= NR / 10; ++i) print b[i] 
}' file
```

Once all the (unsorted) lines are read, `asort` sorts by number in ascending order.

The alternative is to output the result of `sort` to a file, then use something like this:

```
head -n $(( $(wc -l < file) / 10 )) file
```

Bear in mind that shell arithmetic is integer-only, so if you have 1009 lines in your file this will only output 100.

Comment: Both of these worked out perfectly, thank you! I knew there had to be a way to pass the wc -l / 10 formula into the head option but I just simply couldn't find out how. Thanks!